# Simple file urls wordpress, Twenty Thirteen

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I've seen multiple versions of the question and have tried the following to rewrite the css/js/images/fonts/plugins urls in my theme.

However I have not been able to get any of them to work in the Twenty Thirteen theme.
I have forced the htcaccess to display the following with no luck

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/dfi/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) /wp-content/themes/dfi/images/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /wp-content/themes/dfi/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/dfi/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have tried this in the functions.php file in my theme

```
    // rewrite /wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/ to /css/
// rewrite /wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/  to /js/
// rewrite /wp-content/themes/theme-name/img/ to /img/
// rewrite /wp-content/plugins/ to /plugins/

function roots_flush_rewrites() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function roots_add_rewrites($content) {
  $theme_name = next(explode('/themes/', get_stylesheet_directory()));
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $roots_new_non_wp_rules = array(
    'css/(.*)'      => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/css/$1',
    'js/(.*)'       => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/js/$1',
    'img/(.*)'      => 'wp-content/themes/'. $theme_name . '/img/$1',
    'plugins/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/plugins/$1'
  );
  $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $roots_new_non_wp_rules;
}

add_action('admin_init', 'roots_flush_rewrites');

function roots_clean_assets($content) {
    $theme_name = next(explode('/themes/', $content));
    $current_path = '/wp-content/themes/' . $theme_name;
    $new_path = '';
    $content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);
    return $content;
}

function roots_clean_plugins($content) {
    $current_path = '/wp-content/plugins';
    $new_path = '/plugins';
    $content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);
    return $content;
}
```

and a couple others with no avail.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing (code) or where this code should go?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/

If you are using roots starter theme take a look at this plugin too http://roots.io/plugins/roots-rewrites/

Comment: Sorry should have listed that as well! I tried that with no avail.  I feel that this must be a user error on my end, in terms of where I am placing the code and so forth.

Comment: ok can you tell mw what type of server are you using ??
linux, windows ?? apache or nginx ? and also check your server support mod_rewire ? are you getting any kind of error while doing this ??